# Laravel relationships, return boolean

Tags: laravel, lumen

Did anybody figure out if you can return true or false from relationships?

For example i have status and i want to check if current user liked it. But i want to return only true or false, not the whole object with hasOne, because i don't want to return whole object back in JSON response.

I have already tried with

```
public function isLiked()
{
    return count($this->likes()) > 0;
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasOne("\App\Model\Users\Users","id");
}
```

But i always get

**Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
public function isLikedAttribute()//use model mutators
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('likes', $this->relations)) $this->load('likes');
    $likes = $this->getRelation('likes');
    return count($likes) > 0;
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasOne("\App\Model\Users\Users","id");
}
```

& from your controller or from other places you just access like

```
$YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT->isLiked;//replace $YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT with your model object
```

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: can i call it with("isLikedAttribute") then?

Comment: sidenote - there is a relationLoaded function on the model rather than using the long if ( ! array_key_exists('likes', $this->relations)).

Comment: No you will call `with("likes")` `$YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT->likes->first()->isLiked` or loop through `likes` if you have has many relation user to likes else if you have belongs to relation then `$YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT->likes->isLiked`

Comment: Yeah that is what i am trying to skip, to return data directly ... well if it is possible, without any tampering